# How do I run a command before I do an svn commit in Intellij-IDEA?

Tags: java, svn, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I use intellij-idea to commit my code to svn.  Is there any way to run a script before that commit is done?  I would like to run all unit tests before I commit.  This way I *can't* commit if unit tests are failing.

Perhaps there's a way to do this purely with a subversion configuration.  I'd accept that as an answer as long as the commit can be done through the Intellij-IDEA UI.

I'm using Intellij IDEA 13

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK: there is no easy way to achieve this and you'd be better off installing a CI server somewhere on your system. However...

If you really want to do it you could try doing all commits with maven's SCM plugin configured with your svn path and credentials. Then you could create a 'run' configuration in idea which invokes maven with a command string like `mvn clean install scm:checkin`. You could even bind this to a keystroke to make it more like a standard idea feature. You may find problems with the commit message though, although I don't think that this is totally insurmountable.

You're much better off with a CI server though. Jetbrains' TeamCity is free and works really well with IntelliJ. You can configure it to do private builds, which is effectively what you want. If you run it on a server it gets the overhead off your development machine so that you can carry on working while the tests run. If you use git this gets even better.

Comment: Are you saying a local CI server?  We've already got a remote one.  I'd prefer to find the error before I commit, not after.

Comment: I mean a remote CI server. Team City at least, and some others I believe, can perform a remote build. I'm not an expert on the feature, but I believe that IntelliJ ships your changes to team city without a check in, and it then does the build and test for you, performing a commit if everything works. Check out the support page on the subject for more info: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Pre-Tested+%28Delayed%29+Commit

Comment: I would like to suggest that you should accept the answer if you find it adequate and useful. Accepting shows respect to answerer.